# symfony2 assetic causing ajax calls to fail

Tags: ajax, angularjs, symfony, assetic

I have a strange problem.  I am implementing assetic in my Symfony2 application, using the uglifyjs filter.  If I leave my javascript files as individual `<script>` entries, everything works fine.  But as soon as I try using assetic to combine several javascript files, the AJAX calls in my application fail.  The AJAX request is fired, but the response is my login form instead of my JSON data.  I don't understand because I am already logged in when I make the requests.

Here is how I include my JS files:

```
{% javascripts  'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
    'js/fos_js_routes.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/page/extra/spSettings.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/vendor/spin.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/lib/angular-spinner.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/lib/loading.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/lib/notification.js'
    '@MyCoreBundle/Resources/public/js/page/sp_settings.js'
    filter='?uglifyjs2' %}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

What DOES work is if I have all these JS files in the /web directory and reference them using the `asset()` twig function.  If it makes a difference, I am using AngularJS to make the AJAX calls. I am also using FOSJSRoutingBundle to generate routes in my js files (although it appears that the routes are generating fine).

The same thing happens for all AJAX requests on a page.  Has anyone experienced something similar, or knows how to fix this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that may run into this problem... it was just how I was accessing the production environment on my server.  My .htaccess file is configured to load `app_dev.php` by default, so whenever I want to test in the prod environment, I just access it manually by going to `http://mysite.dev/app.php` and this was the problem.  By doing this, my ajax requests are still fired using `http://mysite.dev`, so they are still defaulting to the app_dev.php.

So @jperovic was right, the PHPSESSID for app.php was not being sent.  Instead, the PHPSESSID for app_dev.php was being sent.  Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

And how about executing `AJAX` URL from browser? Does it redirect you to login form?

My first guess would be that, when you fire `AJAX` call, cookies are not being sent over. Look at the following scenarios of `PHPSESSID` cookie:

- you do have active `PHPSESSID` and do have permissions => ALL OK
- you do have active `PHPSESSID` and do not have permissions => `HTTP403 Forbidden`
- you do not have active `PHPSESSID` => HTTP 302 redirection to login form

So, basically, I suspect `PHPSESSID` is not being sent. Can you verify this out via `Firebug`?

**Just a clarification:** by "active `PHPSESSID`" I actually mean "an active session with credentials bound" ;)

Comment: I see that PHPSESSID is sent, but how can I tell in Firebug if it's 'active'?  And you are right, I am also redirected to the login page if I put the request URL in the browser